# How to use a dynamic variable in a Postgresql function call

Tags: postgresql, function

I essentially want to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM 
generate_series(0, 9) as tp
CROSS JOIN 
generate_series(1, maxSch);
```

where maxSch is the maximum value of a column of another table. How could this be accomplished?

The larger problem: I am trying to fill in zeroes in another table for which rows do not exist. For example, `tp` above only goes up to 4 in the other table, but it should go up to 9, and for each missing value (5 through 9), there should be a row for each value from 1 through `maxSch` (this as another column, `sch` ) where another column `value` is 0.

I tried a `WITH` but was unsure how to make it work dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Reading the docs [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) would be a good start.

Comment: Replace `maxSch` with a subquery: `(SELECT max(whatever) FROM sometab)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM
generate_series(0, 9) as tp
CROSS JOIN (
  select generate_series(1, maxSch)
  from (select max(sch) as maxSch from sometable) as _
) as _
```